# How to know what objects have reference to same object (In Debug Mode)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, object, memory-leaks, reference

I need to find all places which have a link to same object. I need to do this because my object never been *garbage collected*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a memory profiler for that. [Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) and [Memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) are decent.

Also, check this question: [Track all object references in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/707421/501518)